# How to make this complex if-else statement maintainable in Kotlin

Tags: java, if-statement, kotlin, simplify

I wrote a function to get information out of the database based on requestparams. The following if-else statement is a huge problem. If we keep adding more filters we need to keep adding statement for all the possible paths.

```
    fun getMessages(name: String, pageable: Pageable, locale: String?, subject: String?,
                              recipient: String?): Page<MessageDTO>? {

        val messagePageable= if (!locale.isNullOrEmpty() && !subject.isNullOrEmpty() && !recipient.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            messageRepository.findAll(where(hasMessageName(name).and(hasLocale(locale!!)
            .and(hasSubject(subject!!).and(hasRecipient(recipient!!))))), pageable)
        } else if (!locale.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            messageRepository.findAll(where(hasMessageName(name).and(hasLocale(locale!!))), pageable)
        } else if (!subject.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            messageRepository.findAll(where(hasMessageName(name).and(hasSubject(subject!!))), pageable)
        } else {
            messageRepository.findAll(where(hasMessageName(name)), pageable)
        }
        return messagePageable.map { messageMapper.toMessageDTO(it) }.takeIf { it.content.isNotEmpty() }
}
```

There should be a better way of writting this. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe some refactoring will help. For example it seems like you're using some sort of `request` to the db, that if filled according to the parameters, so maybe it can be managed like this.

```
fun getMessages(name: String, pageable: Pageable, locale: String?, subject: String?,
                          recipient: String?): Page<MessageDTO>? {
    val request = where(hasMessageName(name))
    locale?.let{ request.and(hasLocale(it)) }
    subject?.let{ request.and(hasSubject(it)) }
    recipient?.let{ request.and(hasRecipient(it))}

    return messageRepository.findAll(request, pageable)
                            .map { messageMapper.toMessageDTO(it) }
                            .takeIf { it.content.isNotEmpty() }
}
```

*Here, I'm not sure how `.and()` method works, so maybe it should be like:
`request = request.and(...)`*

Comment: Thanks for this! This is much better. locale?.let{ request.and(hasLocale(it)) } it will do hasLocale only if it isnt null am i right?

Comment: @J.Adam Correct; the contents will be called only if the value is non-null.  The magic is in the `?.` operator, which calls the following method only if the previous value is not null.  (There's nothing special about the `let()` method for this; it just provides a convenient scope for the action.)

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `if` statement with a [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) statement to make a bit easier to read:

```kotlin
fun getMessages(name: String, pageable: Pageable, locale: String?, subject: String?,
                              recipient: String?): Page<MessageDTO>? = when {
    !locale.isNullOrEmpty() && !subject.isNullOrEmpty() && !recipient.isNullOrEmpty() ->
        messageRepository.findAll(where(hasMessageName(name).and(hasLocale(locale!!)
            .and(hasSubject(subject!!).and(hasRecipient(recipient!!))))), pageable)
    !locale.isNullOrEmpty() ->
        messageRepository.findAll(where(hasMessageName(name).and(hasLocale(locale!!))), pageable)
    !subject.isNullOrEmpty() ->
        messageRepository.findAll(where(hasMessageName(name).and(hasSubject(subject!!))), pageable)
    else ->
        messageRepository.findAll(where(hasMessageName(name)), pageable)
}.map { messageMapper.toMessageDTO(it) }.takeIf { it.content.isNotEmpty() }
```